# SSIS - Read Customer Table, See if File Exists, Attach to Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm working with SSIS and am needing to read all the Customer Numbers out of the Customer table, and search through a directory to see if a PDF file exists with the Customer Number (e.g. A000134) within the filename. If it does, attach it to an email and send.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

How I thought of approaching it was:

1) Loop through the directory and get all the filenames/path and write to a table.

2) Using String Functions, pull the Customer Number out of the filename.

3) Call a Stored Procedure and within the stored proc, loop through all customers who have a file to send (joining on Customer Number between CustomerTable and FilesTable), and use @file_attachments in sp_send_dbmail  to reference the file name to send.

Comment: I suggest you use a for each file loop to loop around the PDF's and inside the loop, search inside your table. Have you tried anything so far? Have you done SSIS development before?

Comment: Hi Nick, yes I have, more looking for ideas. I've updated the question with how I was thinking of approaching it.

Comment: Yes that is exactly how I would do it if I was using SSIS. Don't forget that it's worth having an audit table of files and what state they're in i.e. You should write a time stamp when the file was found and another time stamp when the file was sent.

Comment: Thanks Nick, good to have someone validate my madness :) And for the extra suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

Nice problem but i think SSIS is not right toll to solve this.

Still you can achieve using ssis

1. Load file data in TXT column and use full [text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search) and use
   full-text-search query in ssis
2. Use custom code to look into files using (C# or Vb) for ssis

But My suggestion would be write some stand alone utility to do this job done.